# How to add hours matching a mysql query?

Tags: mysql, datetime, addition, hour

Data (Table name: T1):

| Teacher | Subject | Day | Hour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Albert | Blue | Wednesday | 10:00 |
| Albert | Blue | Wednesday | 12:00 |
| Brandon | Red | Tuesday | 09:00 |
| Brandon | Red | Tuesday | 11:00 |
| Albert | Cyan | Monday | 08:30 |
| Albert | Cyan | Monday | 10:30 |
| Claudia | Gray | Thursday | 08:00 |
| Claudia | Gray | Thursday | 10:00 |
| Albert | Pink | Friday | 13:00 |
| Albert | Pink | Friday | 14:30 |
| Martha | Green | Wednesday | 12:00 |
| Martha | Green | Wednesday | 14:00 |
| Albert | Yellow | Friday | 11:00 |
| Albert | Yellow | Friday | 12:30 |

As it can be seen, there is a record for the starting hour of a Subject and another for the finishing time of the same Subject (data comes like that).
What I intend to know is the weekly amount of hours dedicated to classes by a specific teacher, let's say for "Albert".

Query:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT SUBTIME(max(Hour), min(Hour)) AS TeachTime, Subject FROM T1 WHERE Teachers LIKE '%Albert%' GROUP BY Subject ORDER BY Subject ASC") or die(mysqli_error($link));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!==0) {
echo "Weekly teaching time: ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo $row['TeachTime']." Hrs. ";
}
}
```

Output:

*Weekly teaching time: 02:00 Hrs. 02:00 Hrs. 01:30 Hrs. 01:30 Hrs.*

Desired output:

**Weekly teaching time: 07:00  Hrs.**

As you can see, I don't know how to perform the addition of every resulting amount of hours. How can I achieve that?

I have also tried `GROUP BY Teachers` but results are weird... not the addition result.

Comment: It is a very bad idea to use `die(mysqli_error($$conn));` in your code, because it could potentially leak sensitive information. See this post for more explanation: [mysqli or die, does it have to die?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320411/1839439)

Comment: "As it can be seen, there is a record for the starting hour of a Subject and another for the finishing time of the same Subject"  I only see an `Hour` column, and some guessing is needed to know if it is a start, or and end, time.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the code I end up using thanks to the guidance of [Bill Karwin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20860/bill-karwin) and some more research:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *,
SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(WeekTime))) AS ProfTime FROM
(SELECT *,
SUBTIME(max(Hour), min(Hour)) AS WeekTime FROM T1
WHERE Teacher LIKE '%Albert%' GROUP BY Teacher, Subject) AS C")
or die(mysqli_error($link));
if (mysqli_num_rows($result)!==0) {
echo "Weekly teaching time: ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
echo date('H:i', strtotime($row['ProfTime']))." Hrs. <br>";
}}
```

Bill's answer had made me realize that you can query results from an embedded query, e.g.:

**Query2 over results of (Query1 over data)**

Then, as results of query1 were in time format (*HH:MM*), I should get a total of the addition of all the instances retrieved, i.e., *01:00 + 02:00 + 01:30 = 04:30*

The addition has to be performed in query2 and I have found on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/calculate-total-time-duration-add-time-in-mysql) that the query `SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(Time))) AS TotalTime` does that.

Finally, as the result comes in the the format *HH:MM:SS* and I only need *HH:MM* I applied a php convertion to the output: `date('H:i', strtotime($row['TotalTime']))`.

Answer (score 2):

You know how to get this:

```
mysql> select teacher, day, min(hour), max(hour) 
from T1 where teacher = 'Albert' group by teacher, day;
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| teacher | day       | min(hour) | max(hour) |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
| Albert  | Wednesday | 10:00:00  | 12:00:00  |
| Albert  | Monday    | 08:30:00  | 10:30:00  |
| Albert  | Friday    | 11:00:00  | 14:30:00  |
+---------+-----------+-----------+-----------+
```

And you can use [TIMESTAMPDIFF()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff) to calculate the minutes:

```
mysql> select teacher, day, 
timestampdiff(minute, min(hour), max(hour)) as minutes 
from T1 where teacher = 'Albert' group by teacher, day;
+---------+-----------+---------+
| teacher | day       | minutes |
+---------+-----------+---------+
| Albert  | Wednesday |     120 |
| Albert  | Monday    |     120 |
| Albert  | Friday    |     210 |
+---------+-----------+---------+
```

Now wrap that as a subquery in another aggregation query:

```
mysql> select teacher, sum(minutes) as total_minutes 
from (
  select teacher, day, 
  timestampdiff(minute, min(hour), max(hour)) as minutes 
  from T1 where teacher = 'Albert' group by teacher, day) as t 
group by teacher;
+---------+---------------+
| teacher | total_minutes |
+---------+---------------+
| Albert  |           450 |
+---------+---------------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Bill, doing some little adjustments your solution gave me the expected results, I add the final code I'm using thanks to you.